Policy deny after login does not work with Inertia - laravel
I have a problem with my laravel + inertia application.
Let's say I have this route:
Route::get('/tasks/{task}/apply/', [ApplicationController::class, 'create'])
        ->middleware('auth')
        ->name('applications.create');

As you can see this route is protected by the auth middleware.
In my Controller I am calling a policy:
public function create(Task $task)
{
    Gate::authorize('create', [Application::class, $task]);
}

The policy just always deny the request for this example:
public function create(User $user, Task $task): Response
{
    return Response::deny('You are not allowed to apply to this task.');
}

I did not change the AuthenticatedSessionController.php
/**
 * Handle an incoming authentication request.
  */
 public function store(LoginRequest $request): RedirectResponse
 {
    $request->authenticate();

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    return redirect()->intended(AppServiceProvider::HOME);
 }

I expect my laravel application to behave the following way if I try to access the protected route.

I get redirected to the login page
Logging in with correct credentials
I get redirected back to the expected route
Since the policy denies my request, an 403 error page gets rendered instead of the actual page

Instead the application does the following:

I get redirected to the login page ( as expected )
Log in with correct credentials
The address bar of my browser still is the login uri
A Modal opens and the 403 error page gets rendered inside the Modal ( no redirection to the intended route.

Since a Modal opens this looks like a problem with Inertia to me.
In the chrome developer tools these are my requests:
Request-Url:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/tasks/9c659414-220d-427a-ab16-3fea3a76fdcd/apply
Request-Method:
GET
Statuscode:
302 Found
Remote-Address:
127.0.0.1:8000
Guidelines for referrer URL:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Location: http://127.0.0.1:8000/login
Request-URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login
Request-Method:
GET
Statuscode:
200 OK
Remote-Address:
127.0.0.1:8000
Guidelines for referrer URL:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Request-URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login
Request-Method:
POST
Statuscode:
302 Found
Remote-Address:
127.0.0.1:8000
Guidelines for referrer URL:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Location: http://127.0.0.1:8000/tasks/9c659414-220d-427a-ab16-3fea3a76fdcd/apply
Request-URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/tasks/9c659414-220d-427a-ab16-3fea3a76fdcd/apply
Request-Method:
GET
Statuscode:
403 Forbidden
Remote-Address:
127.0.0.1:8000
Guidelines for referrer URL:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

How can I fix this?
Additional info:

Laravel Version: 11.14.0
PHP Version: 8.2.4
@inertiajs/vue3 Version: 1.2.0

Please let me know if you need additional Info

Ok, it works now. But I don't know if this works for some cases other than inertia redirects:
/**
 * Handle an incoming authentication request.
 */
 public function store(LoginRequest $request): \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse | \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 {
    $request->authenticate();

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    // check if inertia request
    if ($request->inertia()) {
        return Inertia::location(redirect()->intended(AppServiceProvider::HOME)->getTargetUrl());
    } else {
        return redirect()->intended(AppServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
}

Maybe someone can tell me if this correct?!
